# Chang git account on VScode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I just try to push a repo to github , but I get this [dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ry2e0.png)

PS : 4495b is the old account
I can't find a way to change it.

I tried

```sh
git config --global --unset credential.helper
```

- Reinstall git and reconfigure it
- Reinstall VScode

Any ideas how to refresh the given account?

Answer (score 0):

If you confirm that `git config credential.helper` is not set, check first the remote URL with

```
cd /path/to/repo
git remote -v
```

If it is an SSH URL, make sure its associated `~/.ssh/id_rsa`(`.pub`) are not the private/public key of your old account.
Or that `~/.ssh/config` does not reference the SSH private key of your old account.